# Using Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes corrupts the xls/video files?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using the following code to upload files to a FTP, the files get uploaded - the issue is with xls, pdf and video files, they get corrupted. Txt, sql remain intact, i have checked this in the FTP directly. I am thinking its something to do with UTF8.GetBytes? Code is below

```
                Dim URI As String = Url & "/" & fileName
                Dim ftp As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = CType(FtpWebRequest.Create(URI), FtpWebRequest)
                ftp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(Username, Password)
                ftp.Proxy = Nothing
                ftp.KeepAlive = False
                ftp.UsePassive = False
                ftp.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

                Dim sourceStream As New StreamReader(file.InputStream)
                Dim fileContents As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd())
                sourceStream.Close()


                ftp.ContentLength = fileContents.Length
                ftp.UsePassive = True

                Dim requestStream As Stream = ftp.GetRequestStream()
                requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length)
                requestStream.Close()

                Dim response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(ftp.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
Dim fileContents As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd())
```

You're reading the stream as a string, as if it's UTF-8-encoded text, then converting it back to bytes again. Why would you do this? The files in question *aren't* UTF-8-encoded text, so you shouldn't treat them that way.

Read binary data from the stream, *never* converting it into text unless you're sure it really *is* text data. It's not clear what the type of `file` is here, but hopefully you can get the length *without* reading the whole thing into memory. You can then use:

```
file.InputStream.CopyTo(requestStream)
```

to copy all the data. Note that you should use `Using` statements instead of manually closing streams, to avoid leaving them open if exceptions are thrown.